# Talend: parse JSON string to multiple output

Tags: json, talend

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003100/json-parser-for-talend) but I don't believe that there is no solution with standars component. I'm using Talend ESB Studio 5.4.

I have to parse a JSON string from a REST web service into multiple output, and add them to a database.

Database has two tables:

- User (user_id, name, card, card_id, points)
- Action (user_id, action_id, description, used_point)

My JSON Structure is something like that:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "user_id": 1,
            "card": {
                "card_id": "AAA",
                "points": 10
            },
            "actions": [
                {
                    "action_id": 1,
                    "description": "buy",
                    "used_points": 2
                },
                {
                    "action_id": 3,
                    "description": "buy",
                    "used_points": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "user_id": 2,
            "card": {
                "card_id": "BBB",
                "points": -1
            },
            "actions": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "description": "sell",
                    "used_point": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to add a JSON Schema Metadata but it is not clear to me how to "flat" the JSON. I have tried to look at tXMLMap, tExtractJSONFields.. but no luck till now.
I also had a look at tJavaRow but I don't understand how to make a Schema for that.

It's a pity because till now I'm loving Talend! Any advice?

Comment: Why you want to flat a non flat file ? When you create a new json file, the wizard retrieve the schema for you.

Comment: SO I need to save the json file and reload it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a json file in your disk, then create new json file in the metadata of Talend studio, the wizard retrieve the schema for you, after saving, you ca, copie schema in the generic schema of the metadata, and it's done, use that generic schema where you want, this is how to use generic schema in the tRestClient component:

[image]

Comment: with tRestClient I'm keeping on receiving __No message body reader has been found for class : interface org.dom4j.Document, ContentType : text/html.__

Comment: @mcmc I mentioned the tRestClient just to show you how to use the generic schema, please consider to check the [help center](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tRESTClient).